# How to call two procedures from a job in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, job-scheduling

I would like to know how to call two Procedures from a job in Oracle. I had mentioned it like the way i have done it below but i received an error like...

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
    DECLARE
    JOBID NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT ( 
    job => JOBID,
    what => 'BOS_CMSFUNCTIONS.INSERTISAC_EXTRACT@CMSQ7_EXT.WORLD;isacfunctions.getisac_extract',
    next_date=> TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 21/24,
    interval=> 'TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 21/24');
    COMMIT;
    END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 175:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 82
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 139
ORA-06512: at line 4
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to construct a valid PL/SQL block.  Assuming both procedure names are valid and that both procedure calls take no parameters

```
DECLARE
  JOBID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT ( 
    job => JOBID,
    what => 'BEGIN ' ||
            '  BOS_CMSFUNCTIONS.INSERTISAC_EXTRACT@CMSQ7_EXT.WORLD; ' ||
            '  isacfunctions.getisac_extract; ' ||
            'END;',
    next_date=> TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 21/24,
    interval=> 'TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 21/24');
  COMMIT;
END;
```